# ¿Por qué no me coge las comillas correctamente en mi código php?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando mostrar un código HTML a través de PHP como lo muestro en el código, pero tal y como está ahora, me da error en ../avatars, justo ahí, y creo que me debería coger las comillas, pero no me las coge:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['getData']))
    {
        include ('../conexion.php');

        $start = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['start']);
        $limit = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['limit']);

        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM publicaciones ORDER BY id_pub DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";

        if(mysqli_num_rows($consultavistas) > 0)
        {
            $response = "";

            while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
                $response .= "      
                                <div class='card mt-3 border-0 rounded-0'>
                                    <div class='card-body'>
                                        <div class='row'>
                                            <div class='col-sm-2'>
                                                <div class='img-user rounded-circle'>
                                                    <img class='img-fluid-pub' src="'../avatars/<?php echo $data['avatar']; ?>'" alt='User Image'>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='col-sm-10'>
                                                <h3 class='text-muted' onclick='location.href='perfil.php?id=$data['id']''>echo $data['usuario'];</h3><h3>Seguir</h3>
                                                <p><?php echo $lista['fecha']; ?></p>
                                                <p><?php echo $lista['titulo']; ?> Me gusta</p>
                                                <p id="descripcion"><?php echo $lista['descripcion']; ?></p>
                                                <p class="leermas" onclick="leerMas(this);">Leer más...</p>             
                                                <video controls>
                                                    <source src="../anadir-publicacion/publicaciones/<?php echo $lista['video']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                                                    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                                                </video>
                                                <p>Kcal: <?php echo $lista['kcal']; ?> CarbHid: <?php echo $lista['carbohidratos']; ?> Prot: <?php echo $lista['proteinas']; ?> Gras: <?php echo $lista['grasas']; ?> Tiempo: <?php echo $lista['tiempo']; ?>m Personas: <?php echo $lista['personas']; ?> Dinero aprox: <?php echo $lista['precio']; ?>€ Categoría: <?php echo $lista['categoria']; ?></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                ";
            }
        }
    }
    else 
        exit('reachedMax');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usas mal las comillas:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['getData']))
    {
        include ('../conexion.php');

        $start = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['start']);
        $limit = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['limit']);

        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM publicaciones ORDER BY id_pub DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";

        if(mysqli_num_rows($consultavistas) > 0)
        {
            $response = "";

            while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
                $response .= "      
                                <div class='card mt-3 border-0 rounded-0'>
                                    <div class='card-body'>
                                        <div class='row'>
                                            <div class='col-sm-2'>
                                                <div class='img-user rounded-circle'>
                                                    <img class='img-fluid-pub' src='../avatars/".$data['avatar']."' alt='User Image'>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='col-sm-10'>
                                                <h3 class='text-muted' onclick='location.href='perfil.php?id='".$data['id']."'>".$data['usuario']."</h3><h3>Seguir</h3>
                                                <p>".$lista['fecha']."</p>
                                                <p>".$lista['titulo']." Me gusta</p>
                                                <p id='descripcion'>".$lista['descripcion']."</p>
                                                <p class="leermas" onclick='leerMas(this);'>...... etc
?>
```